# Integral of $x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Got the following integral, have no clue:

> $$
> \int_{}^{} x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2} \; dx
> $$

What I tried to do:

1. $$t=a^2+x^2$$

$$dt = 2x\;dx$$

$$x=\sqrt{t-a^2}
$$
2. Got the following integral and got stuck:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{}^{} \sqrt{t}\sqrt{t-a^2} \; dt
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Try  to evaluate the integral by substituting $x=a\tan\theta$, so that
\begin{align}
dx &= a \sec^{2} \theta \\
a^{2}+x^{2} &= a^{2}(1+\tan^{2} \theta)\\
&= a^{2} \sec^{2} \theta \\
& \vdots
\end{align}

Alternatively, alluding to @Did's comment below
\begin{align}
x &= \ \sinh \theta \\
\implies dx &= a \cosh \theta d \theta\\
\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}} &= a\sqrt{1+\sinh^{2} \theta} \\
&= a \cosh \theta \\
\implies \int x^{2} \sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}dx &= \int a^{4}\sinh^{2}\theta  \cosh^{2} \theta d \theta\\
&\vdots  
\end{align}

Comment: Wrong substitution...

Comment: @Did Thank you, brain melt...corrected.

Comment: Or better: $x=a\sinh t$.

Comment: @Did can we solve the integral using $x=ja\cos \theta$, where $j=\sqrt -1$ ?

Comment: @tempx What for? Presumably, $x$ is real hence $x=ia\cos\theta$ implies that $\cos\theta$ is in $i\mathbb R$ hence $\theta$ is in... a strange domain anyway.

Answer (score 1):

$x=a\sinh{t}$ also works: $dx=a\cosh{t}dt$...